# How can I convert query string parameters to look like a directory parts with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-routing

I have an application that is written using `C#` on the top of the ASP.NET Core 3.1 framework.

Typically, Http Get request generates a URL with parameters to look something like this

> **/for_sale/Virginia_Heights/WV?beds=3+&type=MULTI-FAMILY,SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type**

However, I want a way to convert the previous URL to look something like the following instead

> **/for_sale/Virginia_Heights/WV/3+_beds/MULTI-FAMILY,SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type**

Trulia has done something like this on their website (i.e., https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Virginia_Heights,WV/3p_beds/MULTI-FAMILY,SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type/)

If you go to the previous URL and change the filter, you'll notice that any filter you chose will add that filter to the URL as a directory without adding `?=...` query parameters.

I am guessing the URL generation and data fetching are happening using the `AJAX` technique with the help of Javascript. Isn't it? Or, could there be a better way to handle the URL generation?

The part I am struggling with here is building a flexible route in ASP.NET Core that would handle multiple optional parameters.

**Question**
How can I create a route in ASP.NET Core that would allow me to handle such a request with many optional parameters to look like the example above?

Comment: Trulia appears to be a single page application that takes values from the location bar via javascript.  You'll notice they are value-key pairs separated by slashes.  So it goes to it's single-page... javascript parses the location bar, splits by "/", then splits each of those by "[underscore]".  You'll notice if you use two "__" it'll remove that variable from the location bar.  Onhashchange is probably used as an eventhandler to send requests to the server.

Comment: you can use the same strategy and send get/post requests to your different ASP.NET pages using Javascript.  You can return the HTML to the requests, or JSON... then populate your single page accordingly.  (There are a few things to modify to get this to work especially if you use a layout with a renderbody call... you don't really want that if you're going full Ajax... )

Comment: The route seems to be `/for_sale/` followed by all these optional parameters. if you copy/paste the URL into a different browser, you'll notice that all the filters are automaticly selected which is handled by javascript on page load. but how does the routing engine will route such a request? how can I create a route `for_sale` that would allow me to pass as many parameters using `/`

Comment: you basically want to turn off all routing... I'm guessing trulia just does this at the server level... all incoming requests go to a single page.  Then you have a onhashchange function that fires whenever the location changes and you trigger a hashchange on first load.  I guess they use "pushstate" for location bar changes.  I haven't tried that yet, I usually just use a "#" to separate URL from query variables.

Comment: actually looking at the Trulia site again, I think it's only partly a single-page site.  There is some routing happening for the first value... so "/for_sale", "/for_rent", and "/mortgages". I think those are 3 separate routes/pages.  I think the rest of the path is not routed, though... those are treated as query values onhashchange.

Comment: I tried fooling around with setting up routing globally, but it never seemed to take... it sounds like insane_dev's answer below will point your in the right direction... something like {controller}/{var}/{var}/{var}/{var}?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the route like this:

```
[Route("/for_sale/Virginia_Heights/WV/{beds}/{type}]
public IActionResult GetPropertyInfo(string beds, string type)
{
   // .....
}
```

/for_sale/Virginia_Heights/WV of course is not part of the answer. It's whatever your domain and other url structure may be.

Comment: in this case `Virginia_Heights` and `WV` would also be parameters. but what if the user does not select `type` or `beds` what indicate that these are optional parameters?

Comment: @John no, they are not. It depends whether you set a base route for the controller and if there are additional folders or you just want a different url.

Comment: @John check [this](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-routing-in-mvc/) for optional parameters

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by writting the controller method like below.We can specify that the beds and type parameter is from the route using the attribute [FromRoute].

```html
[Route("/for_sale/Virginia_Heights,WV/{beds}/{type}]
public IActionResult GetPropertyInfo([FromRoute]string beds, [FromRoute]string type)
{
   // do something
}

We can also specify other model into it using [FromBody] atrribute.

[Route("/for_sale/Virginia_Heights,WV/{beds}/{type}]
public IActionResult GetPropertyInfo([FromRoute]string beds, [FromRoute]string type,[FromBody]Home model)
{
   // do something
}
```